# Selecting radiobuttons from database?

Tags: vb.net, select

I would like my database to also select radiobuttons from my access database. However whenever I try running my program and providing the needed information, an error shows up

> " Error:Syntax error in string in query expression 'username=asjjm'
>   AND password = 'ksjadklf' AND facultymember = 'False' AND student =
>   'False. "

I don't really understand errors like that because I'm only a beginner. Can someone tell me whats wrong? Thank you very much.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If TxtPassword.Text = "" Or TxtUsername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database2.accdb"

        Try
            'conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Susscess")

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "' AND facultymember = '" & RadioButton1.Checked & "' AND student ='" & RadioButton2.Checked '""
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                MainStud.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Username, Password, and Account Type do not match!", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                TxtPassword.Text = ""
                TxtUsername.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                TxtUsername.Focus()
                conn.Close()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

***Edit**
 I did exactly what @chepe263 said and got two new errors.

> End of statement expected 
>   'System.Data.Sql' is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression. 
>   What's causing these? Note* I made the radiobuttons to indicate choices whether the user is logging in on an account as a faculty member or student.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    ' Check if username or password is empty
    If TxtPassword.Text = "" Or TxtUsername.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Authentication Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        ' Both fields was supply
        ' Check if user exist in database
        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Thesis\Thesis\Database2.accdb"

        Try
            'conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Susscess")

            Dim facultyMemberName As String
            Dim rbdtext As String
            If RadioButton1.Checked Then
                facultyMemberName = RadioButton1.Text
            End If

            If RadioButton2.Checked Then
            rbdtext = RadioButton2.Text
            End If

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "' AND facultymember = '" & facultyMemberName & "' AND student ='" & rbdtext """

            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                MainStud.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match!", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                TxtPassword.Text = ""
                TxtUsername.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                TxtUsername.Focus()
                conn.Close()

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

Edit* Still not over this. Tried every possible solution but still shows errors. Sorry if it could get so confusing. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Take the time and read about SQL injection.

Comment: You have multiple errors in the SQL.  `Password` is a reserved word, so it needs to be escaped, `False` probably probably doesnt need to be escaped.  SQL Parameters fixes many things an will protect you from SQL injection.

Comment: I altered my code but still got an error > Syntax error FROM in clause.
@Plutonix

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_user (...) VALUES ` I don't think this is valid SQL syntax. Perhaps you meant INSERT INTO?

Comment: Your new SQL text is a mix of SELECT and INSERT syntax.  You probably only need `SELECT * FROM bl_user WHERE username = @u AND [Password] = @p`.  Faculty etc will only matter if there is a different John Smith with the same PW.

Comment: http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/

Comment: But how would I select the radiobuttons' values from my database? I also want my system to read the values my user chose when they created their account. Sorry if it's all confusing. Thank you for answering! @ Plutonix

Comment: @Neolisk I do mean the SELECT syntax. It's just all jumbled up and I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you try something like this

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked)
{
rbdtext = RadioButton1.Text;
}
else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
{
rbdtext = RadioButton2.Text;
}
else 
{
rbdtext = RadioButton3.Text;
}
```

then your SQL Statement

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "' AND facultymember = '" & rbdtext  & "' AND student ='" & rbdtext  '""
```

Comment: I don't get it. It tells me that rbdtext is not declared. How do I declare it then?

Comment: I did try it but under one of the rbdtext in the sqlstatement a green line appeared. @Parth akbari

Comment: An error also came up: Variable 'rbdtext' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. @Parth Akbari

Answer (score 0):

declare a new variable inside Button Click's Private sub

```
Dim facultyMemberName as String
```

Do what Parth Akbari suggests

```
If RadioButton1.Checked Then
    facultyMemberName = RadioButton1.Text
End If
```

(Repeat for as many radio buttons you have)

Then place the right variable name and fix the end of your string (the single quote is before the double quote and it makes it a commentary, no good)

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & TxtUsername.Text & "' AND password = '" & TxtPassword.Text & "' AND facultymember = '" & facultyMemberName   & "' AND student ='" & rbdtext  """
```

Tips (just opinions)

- Try using a ListBox or ComboBox instead of RadioButtons since you are listing names of people. You could do something like

  facultyMemberName  = lstFacultyName.SelectedItem.Text
- Try placing your sql query in a textbox, copy it and run it with your favorite SQL manager. You can detect potential errors that way.
- Try using parameters instead of concatenate values to a string.

Comment: It's actually not a list of name. I made those two as choices whether they're a faculty member or student. Also the """ got a blue line beneath it and on the sql dim sqlcom. The errors I got are, end of statement expected and 'System.Data.Sql' is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression. @chepe263

Comment: at the end, you have three """, try with "'" (double quote ", single quote ' , double quote ")

Comment: maybe you could also try ´Dim sqlRead As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader´

Comment: I already have Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader() just after conn.open @chepe263

Comment: but add the keyword "new" after the keyword "As". That way, you create a new instance of the object.

Comment: After I added the keyword new, blue lines appeared below sqlCom.ExecuteReader() and sqlRead in the if statement. "'sqlRead' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." and another End of statement expected. @chepe263